# Infinite strike rate

Tags: cricket, statistics

Debut match of the player, he faces the last ball of the inning when his team requires 6 runs to win. He hits the last ball for a six, its called a no-ball by the umpire. What will be the strike rate of that player, as per statistics, after the match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No-ball is also included for calculating strike rate and in the above case since he has hit 6 in the no-ball, his strike rate will be 600.

Here is a [sample score card](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2013/engine/match/598019.html) which says that the ball faced by Yagnik is 24. If you check the commentary, you can see that he has faced 24 balls out of which 2 were no balls(both of them are shown as 11.3).

Comment: So how many legal deliveries has he faced ? What will be his personal score ? 6 runs in 1 ball or 6 runs in 0 balls ?

Comment: 6 runs in 1 ball. No-ball just gives an extra run and bowler has to bowl extra ball. For batsman it is still a ball he faced. Check the sample score card link. You can understand from that how they calculated it.